# What is the best approach for making major changes to an existing Entity Framework Code First database?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have created an MVC project with Entity Framework Code First.  The project has a decent sized database and is in Production.  Now, I am adding a large new set of features that will pretty much double the size (number of tables) of the database.  As I'm developing it, I expect to make a lot of tweaks to the POCO objects and Fluent model building logic.  But, I don't want to have 100 "migrations" as I make little changes.

If I was doing Database First, I would change the database and recreate the model from it iteratively.  When finished, I could compare the final schema with the previous schema and create the change scripts.

I am inclined to create a new temporary DbContext and develop my Code First model for the new tables there, recreating a new database from scratch as I iterate.  And then when I have the model where I'm happy with it, move it over into the main DbContext and create one big migration.  But this seems painful.  It also has the problem that there are some relationships between new objects and existing objects that need to be put in place.

So, my specific question is how do I make many small changes to a Code First database:

1. Without re-creating the existing database
2. And without creating a (permanent) migration for each change I want to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you created the project with Code First so you I assume you don't need to [reverse engineer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj200620) the database.

To avoid recreating the existing database use a `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` [database initializer](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/)

To avoid creating a permanent migration for each change, you could rollback each minor change then force the migration to re-run.

To rollback: `Update-Database -TargetMigration 0`

To force migration to re-run: `Add-Migration "OneMigrationToRuleThemAll" -Force`

On the other hand....

> Learning to stop sweating the small stuff involves deciding what
>   things to engage in and what things to ignore

(Richard Carlson)

These [tips for Entity Framework migrations](http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/) are worth a read

Comment: Thanks Colin.  The quote from the article "Migrations are very powerful. When they work it’s awesome, but when things go wrong trying to determine what happened can be extremely frustrating." is right on the money.  Regarding the "stop sweating" quote, I'm not sure I get your point.  I mean I like and totally agree with the quote, but I just want to make sure I take a sensible approach before I make a mess of the database.  Am I over thinking this?

Comment: I have about 50 migrations to go before I reach 100. But I'm sure I'll get there eventually. Just keep that folder shut as much as you can if it bothers you.

Comment: Okay, I've learned to stop fearing migrations and embrace them.  Exercise the migrations, bring new ones up and take them down.  Don't worry about how many you create...  Thanks Colin.

Comment: :-) I do throw back the tiddlers though